# Looping list in WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm trying to loop through a list of links, and perform some actions with each one. WebdriverIO are synchronous for test code like following(mocha) for all their API. But how to integrate existing node.js code for synchronous flow. For following code

```
    const assert = require('assert');
    const webdriverio = require('webdriverio')

    describe('webdriver.io page', function() {

            it('should be a pending test');

            before(() => {

                var options = {
                    desiredCapabilities: {
                        browserName: 'chrome'
                    }
                };

                client = webdriverio.remote(options)
                return client.init();

            })
            after(function() {
                browser.end();
            });

            it('should have the right title - the fancy generator way', function () {
                var list = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.github.com"]

                for(var i = 0 ; i < list.length;i++){
                    browser.url(list.length);
                    var title = browser.getTitle();
                    browser.saveScreenshot('./snapshot' + i + '.png').call(function(){
                        fs.exists(screenshotPath, function(fileExists) {
                            fileExists.should.be.true;
                            done();
                        })
                    });
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please give some more info

Comment: I would like to know how to control the Webdriver.io in specific order from newbies that doesn't know much about Promise. Although the above is working on Test runner like wdio testrunner but i haven't try out. Other options would be async/await or nest promised calls

Comment: According to this link: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2312

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 other options for you for a sync loop

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/serial-loop
```

or you can create your own loop like this

```
function testonly() {
//.. do some stuff
// when done make again 
testonly()

// when you finish with your stuff you can start a new function as example after()
if(test == 'test') {
after() 
}

}

function after() {
//..    
}
```

Or you can use the callback method. Hope this was what you were looking for. Of course you can use webdriver.io stuff in this loops!